# How to use QDataStream::readBytes()

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.4

According to [the documentation for `readBytes()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#readBytes) (in Qt 5.4's QDataStream), I would expect the following code to copy the `input_array` into newly allocated memory and point `raw` at the copy:

```
QByteArray input_array{"\x01\x02\x03\x04qwertyuiop"};
QDataStream unmarshaller{&input_array, QIODevice::ReadOnly};

char* raw;
uint length;
unmarshaller.readBytes(raw, length);

qDebug() << "raw null? " << (raw == nullptr) << " ; length = " << length << endl;
```

...but the code prints `raw null?  true  ; length =  0`, indicating that no bytes were read from the input array.

Why is this? What am I misunderstanding about `readBytes()`?

Comment: The `QByteArray` constructor needs a nul terminated char array if you don't specify the size.

Comment: @cmannett85 Ah, thanks. But if I read off a series of `quint8`s using `>>` first, I get the expected `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, which seems to imply that I am indeed constructing the expected QByteArray....right?

Comment: @cmannett85 Also, I can print the QByteArray with `qDebug()`.

Comment: @cmannett85 Finally, adding `\0` at the end of the `input_array` constructor string doesn't appear to change the code's behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation does not describe this clearly enough, but `QDataStream::readBytes` expects the data to be in a certain format: `quint32` part which is the data length and then the data itself.

So to read data using `QDataStream::readBytes` you should first write it using `QDataStream::writeBytes` or write it any other way using the proper format.

An example:

```
QByteArray raw_input = "\x01\x02\x03\x04qwertyuiop";

QByteArray ba;

QDataStream writer(&ba, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
writer.writeBytes(raw_input.constData(), raw_input.length());

QDataStream reader(ba);

char* raw;
uint length;
reader.readBytes(raw, length);

qDebug() << "raw null? " << (raw == NULL) << " ; length = " << length << endl;
```

Also you can use `QDataStream::readRawData` and `QDataStream::writeRawData` to read and write arbitrary data.

Comment: Ah, I took that to mean that the resulting `char` array would start with 4 bytes for length.